# Should I fit a function to this lightcurve?

Tags: python, light-curve

I am creating a light curve for the duration of a binary system in order to find out the duration of the eclipse. I am unsure as to whether to fit a function to the data (is it appropriate) as by fitting the function I am expressing that I think that the data lies within this region.

I was thinking of maybe doing the fit piecewise but I am unsure if I should even fit it at all. Any reading material or help would be great. I just need a pointer in the right direction.

I've attached two images. One plot without a fit and one plot with a cubic function fitted to the graph.

Many thanks in advance,
Owen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you try fitting a periodic function to graph the light curve.

Comment: You need to use error bars to show the accuracy of the measurements.  What a "reasonable" fit would be is hard to gauge without knowing the measurement error ranges.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That helps. I will also try to repost with errors.